# Email blast mailing through CiviCRM

Tags: email

How can I send an e-blast email mail to groups from different states after pulling a report in CSV FORMAT from CiviCRM

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create groups in Civi based on which state they are in then send the email out of Civi mail. Use the advanced search to find the contacts, select the ones you want included in the group, then select Group - Add contacts. Select Create new group, name it and select mailing list from the group type and save.

In the mailings drop down, select new mailing, format however you want and select which group you want it to go to. That way you can track opens and which links have been opened by each person. You can also include attachments to this email.

Comment: This may sound silly, I followed the steps and can not seem to get the test message sent.  Suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your help, i figured out the hold up issue.